# Error in svd(c) : infinite or missing values in 'x' when applying synthetic control using the Synth Package

Tags: r

I am trying to implement synth control and placebo tests using the Texas.dta available at this website:

https://www.scunning.com/mixtape.html

I downloaded the synth file texas13.dta and used the `readstata13` package to read it. so far so good.

I used `dataprep` to create the data necessary to run `synth` so I can afterwards use the `generate.placebos` function. This latter function is the problem:

-I am using a package from:

```
install_github('bcastanho/SCtools')
library(SCtools)
```

This is the necessary library to create the placebos for randomization inference.

When I try to run the generate.placebos (which basically I believe is just a permutation between the controls), I get an error:

```
Error in svd(c) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

It seems only with some particular states this occurs since it pops out after a number of permutations.

I've tried changing the states I was using (ie, excluding some of them)

I also tried one by one manually instead of using the placebo function and it also breaks for some states (like Michigan)

```
dataprep.out = dataprep(
  foo = texas,
  predictors = c("income", "ur", "poverty"),
  predictors.op = "mean",
  time.predictors.prior = c(1985:1993),
  special.predictors = list(
    list("bmprison", c(1990,1992,1991,1988), "mean"),
    list("alcohol", 1990, "mean"),
    list("aidscapita", c(1990,1991), "mean"),
    list("bmprison", c(1988,1990:1992), "mean"),
    list("alcohol", 1990, "mean"),
    list("aidscapita",  1990:1991, "mean"),
    list("black", 1991:1992, "mean"),
    list("perc1519", 1990, "mean")),
  dependent = "bmprison",
  unit.variable = "statefip",
  unit.names.variable = "state",
  time.variable = "year",
  treatment.identifier = 48,
  controls.identifier = statefiplist[!statefiplist %in% 48],
  time.optimize.ssr = 1985:1993,
  time.plot = 1985:2000
)

synth.out = synth(dataprep.out)
placebos = generate.placebos(dataprep.out, synth.out)
```

The expected output is to have the placebo data which I can plot.

Comment: I believe that it indicates that you have some missing data and the function using `svd` won't work. You would need to say `na.omit(texas)` or `complete.cases(texas)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had been encountering the same problem for some weeks, and I finally figured out how to solve it (at least with my data). I simply changed the argument 'Sigf.ipop' from 5 (default) to 2. This parameter is described as "The Precision setting for the ipop optimization routine," so I assume this change makes the optimization process less rigorous.

In summary, my previous code was:

```
placebo <- generate_placebos(
  dataprep.out_baseline,
  synth.out_baseline,
  Sigf.ipop = 5,
  strategy = "multicore"
)
```

It was returning the same error (Error in svd(c): infinite or missing values in 'x'). The new code that works is:

```
placebo <- generate_placebos(
  dataprep.out_baseline,
  synth.out_baseline,
  Sigf.ipop = 2,
  strategy = "multicore"
)
```

I chose Sigf.ipop = 2 because this number is used multiple times in the package's GitHub documentation."